# WebSphere 8.5 - Not stopping on Windows

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, ear

Newbie to WebSphere. I deployed EAR in WAS and started the application. Everything is fine. I updated some hTML stuff and created EAR again, and I went to `WebSphere Enterprise Application`. Selected my application and clicked on `Update` button. I chose my new EAR and clicked on `Next` button. It keeps going forever. So I tried to stop the server and now it does not stop, the Admin console doesn't open any page well.

I tried to stop this from command prompt as well. `stopServer <servername> -username <u> -password <pw>`. It just hangs at `Reading configuration for the server <servername>`. And when this happens, the Laptop heats up like hell.

When this happened first time, I had to restart the Laptop. Its happening again.

Where is the problem? Any issue with "updating" ear?

Comment: Maybe you are low on memory and using pagefile? Or have some problem with antivirus or disk? If not, and if your ear is very big you may need to increase JVM heap size. If your process hangs you can always kill it from the task manager to save your laptop ;-)

Comment: @Gas Thanks. I am aware of killing the respective process. But this thing does not work. As for the memory, I have freaking 16G RAM. :-). My ear is not that big. The initial deploy went fairly quickly. The problem is when I `update` it.

Comment: Which version you have? Run the versionInfo.bat scirpt. Maybe install fixpack if you are on x.0 . For other test you could create second profile and test there to check if your profile is not broken.

Comment: @Gas Version 8.0.0.8. I guess there is no Fixpack for this version?

Comment: There is 8.0.0.9. But I'd just create second profile for test first. As this is very unusual behavior. Any messages in the SystemOut.log or it just hangs?

Comment: It just hangs there. So 3 things: 1. Not sure why EAR is not getting updated, it just hangs there. 2. When I try to stop the server, it does not stop. It just hangs. 3. System heats up when this happens. Will try creating another profile. I tried this 3 times. Same thing everytime. I have had to restart my laptop.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue. I solve this by following below steps.
Go to Task Manager in your system > click on Process>Then kill the java.exe instances.